# Error generating maven documentation

Tags: java, maven-2

When I run `mvn site` I get the error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.codehaus.mojo.versions.ordering.MavenVersionComparator.innerGetSegmentCount(MavenVersionComparator.java:5
1)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.versions.ordering.AbstractVersionComparator.getSegmentCount(AbstractVersionComparator.java:
27)
```

This appears to be a Maven bug, which according to [the JIRA ticket](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MVERSIONS-89?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel&focusedCommentId=221603#action_221603) has been resolved in version 1.2. I'm assuming this means version 1.2 of a particular plugin (probably the site plugin).

Does anyone know whether this fix has been released, and if so, how can I force Maven to use the version of the plugin that includes this fix?

**Update**

As suggested below, I added

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>versions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.2</version>                
</plugin>
```

to my pom.xml. But I now get the following error instead:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.codehaus.mojo.versions.PluginUpdatesDetails.isDependencyUpdateAvailable(PluginUpdatesDetails.java:68)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.versions.PluginUpdatesRenderer.renderSummaryTotalsTable(PluginUpdatesRenderer.java:132)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.versions.PluginUpdatesRenderer.renderBody(PluginUpdatesRenderer.java:71)
```

Thanks,
Don

Comment: I saw something like this when using maven 3.0-beta-1.  Try using an older version to see if it goes away.

Answer (score 1):

It's the Codehaus [Versions Maven Plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/).

Here's the config with the version you need:

```
<reporting>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
      <artifactId>versions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.2</version>
      <reportSets>
      ...
      </reportSets>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</reporting>
```

---

Edit:

For the new error, [this source code line](http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/xref/org/codehaus/mojo/versions/PluginUpdatesDetails.html#68) (68) suggests that a dependency is referenced without a version. Try looking for a plugin without a `<version>`.

```
63      public boolean isDependencyUpdateAvailable()
64      {
65          for ( Iterator i = dependencyVersions.values().iterator(); i.hasNext(); )
66          {
67              ArtifactVersions versions = (ArtifactVersions) i.next();
68              if ( versions.getAllUpdates( UpdateScope.ANY, includeSnapshots ).length > 0 )
69              {
70                  return true;
71              }
72          }
73          return false;
74      }
```